# Quiver vector length in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've written this:

```
[T,Y]=meshgrid(-4:0.5:4,-4:0.5:4);
S=-(2-Y).*Y;
L=sqrt(1+S.^2);
quiver(T,Y,1./L,S./L)
axis tight
shg
```

And all the arrows are the same length. But when I try this:

```
t=linspace(-2,2,16);
y=linspace(-4,4,16);
[T,Y]=meshgrid(t,y);
S=Y./T+3*T;
L=sqrt(1+S.^2);
quiver(T,Y,1./L,S./L)
axis tight
```

I get this image:

[image]

The arrows are not all the same length. Does anyone have an explanation? I'm using Matlab R2017b.

Comment: The arrows are the same (Euclidean) length, it's just that your plot is stretched in the x-direction. If you use `axis equal`, then all of the arrows will be the same length visually as well.

Comment: @beaker Thanks for the insight. That helps me understand what is going on.